# How to set default type as ZIP or RAR

Tags: php, zip

I have created a file using touch variable in `PHP`.

How can I set the default type as `ZIP` or `RAR` of a file NOT folder (PHP creates zip folder and put file in it, but I want to make `ZIP` or `RAR` file) ?

```
touch(filename);
```

but the function can't take "TYPE" in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The `touch` function was not explicitly designed for creating files, it was designed to update the timestamp of a file. As a side effect of the timestamp update, if the file is not pre-existing, then it will be created.

If you want to do anything with zip archives, it is best to use PHP's `ZipArchive` class.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE|ZipArchive::OVERWRITE) === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile('verylargetextfile.txt', 'whatItWillBeCalledInTheZip.txt');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'Zip archive Created!' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Could not create Zip Archive!' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

`ZipArchive::addFile` allows one to put a file in the top level of the Zip Archive, so that it will not be enclosed in a folder, i.e.:

```
$ touch verylargetextfile.txt
$ php -fziptest.php
Zip archive Created!
$ unzip test.zip               # Will create whatItWillBeCalledInTheZip.txt in the working directory
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) for more information.